# autocomplete-light not showing up in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to install the autocomplete-light function in my admin menu. I have added the following in my admin.py.  I have install the app in my settings.

```
class InstitutionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Institution, exclude = [])
    list_display = ('name', 'url',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('name')

admin.site.register(Institution, InstitutionAdmin)
```

added this to autocomplete_light_registry.py:

```
autocomplete_light.register(InstitutionAdmin)
```

I don't think I need to at the autocomplete to url right? because this should show up when I go to the admin page in django? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do `autocomplete_light.register()` for every model you want to be autocompleted in InstitutionAdmin.form.

http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#autocomplete_light.registry.AutocompleteRegistry.register